# why can not run go function in go?

Tags: go

This is the below code:

```
func main() {
    values := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    for _, v := range values {
        go func(x int) {
            fmt.Println(x)
        }(v)
    }
}
```

If this code have not `go` keyword, it will print `1, 2, 3, 4`.

But it can not print any code now, why?

go version: 1.5.2 darwin/amd64

Answer (score 2):

Short: Place a wait at the end and it will print.
Better option: communicate termination via channels.

Long: A go program lives as long as the main goroutine lives.

When you do `go somefunc()`, it's not started immediately, the somefunc() gets *scheduled*.

In your case you schedule some goroutines and quit – and there's no reason for the scheduler to run other goroutines.